# How can I find my Minecraft seed on Xbox 360

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I am trying to make a mini-game server and I need the world seed so I can find a map of it to put the domination control points for a mini-game.

Answer (score 1):

When you launch Minecraft you should be able to find this by clicking on Play Game, this will then take you to the listing of maps that you have save.

If you select the world you want to use you it should bring up a little detailed tab as below. Then there should be a Seed: - section that you can get it from.

[image]